# Can the original Age of Empires II be played online thru GameRanger with the HD version on Steam?

Tags: steam, age-of-empires-ii-the-age-of-kings, age-of-empires-ii-hd, gameranger

So my question is if the original Age of Empires 2 can be played online with the Steam HD version of the same game through the [GameRanger](http://www.gameranger.com/) software, not through Steam?

Comment: Have you tried?  We have a question that's just about old AoE2 <--> Aoe2 HD, [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/112810/can-the-original-age-of-empires-ii-be-played-online-with-the-hd-version-on-steam).  Either way, that question answers this one.

Answer (score 4):

GameRanger and Steam are two entirely different networking protocols, so **no**, you won't be able to make it work between the two. It *may* be possible to make support for AoE2 HD use GameRanger, but it is completely unknown if the two versions would be compatible that way.